# dividing a data file to new files based on data on a particular column

Tags: awk

I have a data file (data.txt) as shown below:

```
0  25  10  25000
1  25  7   18000
1  25  9   15000

0  20  9   1000
1  20  8   800
0  20  8   900

0  50  10  4000
0  50  5   2500
1  50  10  5000
```

I want to copy the rows with same value in the second column to separate files. I want to get following three files:

data.txt_25

```
0  25  10  25000
1  25  7   18000
1  25  9   15000
```

data.txt_20

```
0  20  9   1000
1  20  8   800
0  20  8   900
```

data.txt_50

```
0  50  10  4000
0  50  5   2500
1  50  10  5000
```

I have just started learning awk. I have tried the following bash script:

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2 
  3 for var in 20 25 50
  4 do
  5         awk -v var="$var" '$2==var { print $0 }' data.txt > data.txt_$var
  6 done
```

While the bash script does what I want it to do, it is time consuming as I have to put the values of second column data in line 3 manually.

So I would like to do this using awk. How can I achieve this using awk ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On SO we do encourage users to add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems, so kindly do add the same in your question and let us know then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following, this considers that your 2nd column numbers are NOT in sorted form.

```
sort -k2 Input_file | 
awk '
prev!=$2{
  close(output_file)
  output_file="data.txt_"$2
}
{
  print > (output_file)
  prev=$2
}'
```

In case your Input_file's 2nd column is sorted then no need to use sort you could directly use like:

```
awk '
prev!=$2{
  close(output_file)
  output_file="data.txt_"$2
}
{
  print > (output_file)
  prev=$2
}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding a detailed explanation for above.

```
sort -k2 Input_file |            ##Sorting Input_file with respect to 2nd column then passing output to awk
awk '                            ##Starting awk program from here.
prev!=$2{                        ##Checking if prev variable is NOT equal to $2 then do following.
  close(output_file)             ##Closing output_file in back-end to avoid "too many files opened" errors.
  output_file="data.txt_"$2      ##Creating variable output_file to data.txt_ with $2 here.
}
{
  print > (output_file)          ##Printing current line to output_file here.
  prev=$2                        ##Setting variable prev to $2 here.
}'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would be very glad if you could explain your answer a bit.

Comment: @physu, Added detailed explanation now, kindly do check and lemme know if any queries here.

Answer (score 2):

For the given sample, you can also use this:

```
awk -v RS= '{f = "data.txt_" $2; print > f; close(f)}' data.txt
```

- `-v RS=` paragraph mode, empty lines are used to separate input records
- `f = "data.txt_" $2` construct filename using second column value (by default awk split input record on spaces/tabs/newlines)
- `print > f` write input record contents to filename
- `close(f)` close the file